# How to execute a date function inside an awk command in an fast way?

Tags: performance, bash, date, awk, cygwin

I am reading a file using awk and parsing the date and converting it into seconds. I wrote a working code that achieves this but it runs relatively slow and I have large log files that I intend to read. I need to know if there is another way that can achieve this in less time. Here is my code:

```
awk '
 {
  currentDateTime=$1 " " $2
  seconds ="date \"+%s\" -d \""currentDateTime" \""
  print "The time in seconds is: [ " seconds "]"
  seconds | getline result
  print result 
 }'  out.log
```

Here is the output:

```
The time in seconds is: [ date "+%s" -d "2014-04-01 10:20:22,357 "]
1396336822
```

Note that in the first output, the variable currentDateTime is outputted as a command and not as a value. I am wondering if I could execute this command without using getline since the getline seems slow when trying it out on larger files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `getline` is slow is that in this case you are running a shell command.

That's what is slow.

You are spawning a new shell and running `date` in it for each entry.

Stop doing that.

Use the GNU awk `mktime` function if you are using GNU awk.

Comment: Thanks this helped and gave me results in no time.